# MATLAB read multiple excel files

Tags: excel, matlab

I want to compare between 20 files. How can I access them without making 20 variables. I tried making an array but from some reason it doesn't recognize the number.

```
for i=1:20
     m=strcat(char(i),".csv");
     t(i)=readtable(m);
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `num2str(i)` instead of `char(i)`. This is because `char(i)` uses the ASCII mappings (you'd get weird symbols).